# ios 10 programmatically turn on compass calibration in Location Services?

Tags: ios, cllocation, compass, heading

I was trying to figure out why the CLLocationManager true heading always
returned -1.0.  I found that Settings->Privacy->Location Services->System Services->Compass Calibration switch needed to be enabled.

Now Im trying to find how to automatically take the user there to correct
the issue when its not turned on.

I know I can take them to the GPS Settings by doing:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]]
```

but that does not take me to the Compass Calibration Setting.

Anyone know if its possible and how?
Thanks!